# Laravel returns template instead of error message

Tags: laravel

I use Laravel and axios to store data. If there is an error server side, the first time, Laravel returns the full html page instead of the error message. If i click a second time to store data, it returns the error message.

Response after first click:

[image]

Response after second click:

[image]

Does anybody have an idea why this happens. Thanks in advance

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Project;

use App\Http\Controllers\DataTableController;

use App\Models\Project\Project\Project;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ProjectController extends DataTableController
{
    public function builder()
    {
        return Project::query();
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return view('projects.index');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateStoreData($request);

        $request->merge(['creator_id' => Auth::id(), 'company_id' => Auth::user()->company_id]);

        $model = $this->builder->create($request->only($this->getUpdatableColumns()));

        return $model;
    }
```

Important: Not the error himself is the problem. The problem is, that laravel response the content of the page and not the error message!

Comment: Maybe your company_id in your model is in guard array and you shoud put it in fillable

Comment: Please share your controller.

Comment: You can use the try..catch blocks or modify the Exception Handler to return a JSON response if an error is thrown. 

On an additional note: Since you're merging creator_id and company_id with the request params, make sure that the getUpdatableColumns() includes the company_id field. The error is because you're not passing the company_id to create a new record in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined any default value to `company_id` and saving a blank value to `company_id`

To solve this error create  a default value in your mirgration or pass a valid value

```
$table->integer("company_id")->default(0);
```

Comment: The problem with the compan_id is solved.This is not my issue. The issue is, that the response is wrong.

Comment: please share your controller's function code where you are storing data